# Android Dev and Class MediaRecorder to record the activity of the mobile phone?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, record, mediarecorder

Does anyone know how should I use the class MediaRecorder to record the activity of the phone screen? That is, instead of taking a static snapshot, I want to capture it as a video. I know that the camera API starts the process of encoding the video and so on, but i wonder if there is a way to make it see the very screen of the device as the "camera". Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> i wonder if there is a way to make it see the very screen of the device as the "camera"

No.

But, on Android 5.0+ devices, you can use [the media projection APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) to record a screencast. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MediaProjection/andcorder).